# Make emacs run in console mode (-nw) by default

Tags: emacs

How can I make Emacs run in terminal (or console) mode by default, as if I'd used `-nw`? And once that's done, how do I force it to run in GUI mode (once) if I need to?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

On my Debian testing, `alias emacs='emacs -nw'` followed by `emacs` opens Emacs in the terminal. And, in the same session, `emacs23-x` opens Emacs with the GUI.

Comment: or `\emacs` for the X version. This will call the original emacs not the alias. I have three alias, `enw='\emacs -nw -name -bg black -fg white  -bd ForestGreen'`, `emacsx='\emacs -name Editor_Emacs_$USER@$HOST  -geometry 80x50  -bg black -fg white  -bd ForestGreen'` and `emacs='enw'` to make the *nw* de default one.

Answer (score 14):

In case you decide to use emacs in terminal mode **always**, install emacs-nox (emacs with no X support).

After installationis still ran by $ emacs so you no need to create aliases again!:)

Its there in repos of Debian Squeeze so must be in Ubuntu also.

Answer (score 4):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/236008/6418) suggests the method I found works best for me (was having problems with aliases). Essentially, create an executable script

```
#!/bin/sh
emacs -nw "$@"
```

and point `$EDITOR` to it in your shell rc file.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem and didn't want to set an alias (because I also wanted "emacs -nw" to be my default shell EDITOR but it wouldn't work) so I started grepping around and saw this line in `configure`

```
If you are sure you want Emacs compiled without X window support, pass
--without-x to configure.
```

So, if you want to download and build from source, you can just do

```
curl http://gnu.mirrors.hoobly.com/emacs/emacs-25.3.tar.xz
tar -xvzf emacs-25.3.tar.xz && cd emacs-25.3
./configure --without-x
make && sudo make install
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alias emacs='emacs -nw'
```

Or

```
unset DISPLAY
```

Comment: clearing DISPLAY works but it assumes you don't want to run any other X programs.